# Why val loss increasing while val accuracy remain increasing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am training a simple cifar10 classification neural network. During the training, I found something weird. Here is my plot of learning curve and accuracy.

It is my cross entropy loss of training and testing (red is testing, blue is training)

[image]

It is my classification accuracy of training and testing (color same above)

[image]

I always think the loss and accuracy is consistent invertly. Who can give me some reason about how it happend? Thanks anyway!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258166/good-accuracy-despite-high-loss-value/281651#281651 This link might interest you.

Comment: @TusharGupta thank you very much! but I still feel confused about it, could you please give me some your own opinions, I read your link , and it said the a became much larger than correct a (0.3), may I think it is a kind of overfitting?